# Proof of the projection formula $(\pi^*D)\cdot D'=D\cdot (\pi_*D')$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following (simplified) version of the projection formula

> Let $S',S$ be non-singular algebraic surfaces and $\pi:S'\to S$ a birrational map between them. If $D\in \text{Div}(S)$ and $D'\in \text{Div}(S')$, then:
> $$(\pi^*D)\cdot D'=D\cdot(\pi_*D')$$

By linearity, we may just consider $D, D'$ prime divisors.

Let $X\subset S'$ and $Y\subset S$ closed sets such that $\pi:S'\setminus X\to S\setminus Y$ is an isomorphism.

The claim is obviously true if $D\subset S\setminus Y$ and $D'\subset S'\setminus X$.

Now if $D'\cap X\neq \emptyset$ or $D\cap Y\neq\emptyset$, I don't know what to do.

In the particular case $\pi:S'\to S$ is the blow-up at the point $P\in S$ with $E:=\pi^{-1}(P)$, I was able to deal with some specific divsors. For example, when $D'=E$ and $D=C$ where $C$ is a curve through $P$. If $m$ is the multiplicity of $P$ in $C$, we can use the formula $\pi^*(C)=\widetilde{C}+mE$.

The result for this specific case was not so evident (in my opinion) and I still can't see how the general case should go.

Answer (score 1):

Nine months later, I'll post the answer I was pregnant with.

Since a birrational morphism between smooth surfaces is a composition of blowups and isomorphisms, it is enough to consider $\pi$ as a single blowup.

By linearity, it is enough to consider $D,D'$ prime divisors. We have two cases:

(1) $D'=E$. Let $\widetilde{C}$ be the stric transform of $C$. We have the formula $\pi^*C=\widetilde{C}+mE$, where $m$ is the multiplicity of $P$ in $C$. Therefore $(\pi^*C)\cdot E=\widetilde{C}\cdot E-m=0$. But since $\pi_*E=0$, we get $C\cdot (\pi_*E)=0$ and we're done.

(2) $D'\neq E$. In this case $\pi_*D'=\pi(D')$ and $D'$ is the strict transform of $\pi(D')$, therefore $\pi^*(\pi_*D)=D'+mE$. By the previous case, $(\pi^*C)\cdot E=0$, so:
\begin{align*}
(\pi^*C)\cdot D'&=(\pi^*C)\cdot(\pi^*(\pi_*D)-mE)\\
&=(\pi^*C)\cdot (\pi^*(\pi_*D))\\
&=C\cdot (\pi_*D).
\end{align*}

(Here we've used the fact that $(\pi^*D_1)\cdot (\pi^*D_2)=D_1\cdot D_2$ for any divisors $D_1,D_2$ in $S$). $_\blacksquare$